# has graph isomorphism been solved? question

Tags: discussion

re the question ["has graph isomorphism been solved"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/has-the-graph-isomorphism-problem-been-solved). this question asking about accuracy of an arxiv preprint claiming to prove graph isomorphism is now up to 9v. added an "answer" which gilles quickly deleted (even with one upvote in its brief appearance). think its great that this question stayed open without close votes and got good answers. however, its something of an anomaly. also, the 2nd top answer by Yuval now at 10v has an offhand remark

> (If it had been, I would have known about it.)

which inspired my response which looks at how proofs in general are accepted by a scientific community incl wrt modern aspects (eg arXiv). agreed it is somewhat circuitous in answering the question but feel its all relevant.

Comment: The deleted post has no relevance here as it's not about [cs.SE], so I removed it from the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear what the question here is besides a complaint, "why has my question been deleted". So I will answer to that.

The deleted post had three downvotes and one flag when it was deleted. It did not answer the question, and did not attempt to. Hence it was rightfully deleted.

The advice you were given in a comment is sound: blog posts belong on your blog.

Comment: am not asking why the answer was deleted, gilles explained that. the other answers use indirect criteria in answering the question, along with yuvals offhand comment. so the "answer" (attempt) looked at indirect criteria in general, correct/ incorrect papers in arxiv, cstheory guidelines on topic quoted, etc.

Comment: @vzn You aren't asking why the answer was deleted? Then what are you asking? Speak English instead of stream-of-consciousness if you want people to listen to you.

Comment: huh. _everything_ has to be a Q/A? seems kind of awkward at times. ok, asking for [tag:discussion]...? esp by anyone who uses the site other than _mods_...?

Comment: @vzn Discussion is fine. It usually starts with a question, a hypothesis or a problem statement. Note how your "question" above does not contain either.

Comment: ok. the problem is that the answer which involved significant research/ writing effort with lots of (scientific/ mathematical) refs, some to TCS areas, etc got deleted.

Comment: @vzn My problem with your answer was that it did not answer the question (I was one of the people downvoting it). If a question asks "has X been solved?", I wouldn't expect a answer which is a "general meta-note also based on mathematics, scientific philosophy, psychology, and sociology". Regardless of whether your writing is a good or useful answer to *some* question, I didn't think it was really on point here.

Comment: @Juho np, thx for your pov/ clarification, not overly upset by downvotes, actually anticipated/ expected some, figured the writing might be regarded by some as "examining dirty laundry" or whatever and was wondering myself what the votes would end up as a metric of approval/ agreement. other answers use indirect means/ criteria of evaluation of the paper in question, and mine did indeed take it further. it seems the flag by _?_ (presumably not a mod) was what really triggered the death sentence process/ hammer/ guillotine :(